# Testing log out with Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, testing, postman, laravel-passport

I'm trying to figure out how to test my Passport-driven logout function, which looks like this:

```
public function logout() {
        $accessToken = auth()->user()->token();

        $refreshToken = DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
            ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
            ->update([
                'revoked' => true
            ]);

        $accessToken->revoke();

        return response()->json(['status' => 200]);
    }
```

I am using the Passport actingAs helper in setting up the response.

```
    Passport::actingAs(
            $user,
            ['read write']
        );
$response = $this->post('/logout')
                ->assertStatus(200);
```

The test fails, as the code gives a 500 error, as `auth()->user()->token()` is ... empty-ish? `$accessToken->id` is 0, for example, which it shouldn't be, which means the code fails.

What I'm not sure about is if this is expected behavior because of how Passport's actingAs helper works and I can't actually test the logout function, or if there's something wrong with my logout function. Halp!

My routes:

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

JsonApi::register('v1', ['namespace' => 'Api'], function (Api $api, $router) {
    $api->resource('training-locations');
    $api->resource('courses');
});
```

ETA: My login function, if it's helpful:

```
public function login(Request $request, Client $client){
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $response = $client->post(config('app.url') . '/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => config('auth.proxy.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('auth.proxy.client_secret'),
                'grant_type' => config('auth.proxy.grant_type'),
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scopes' => '[read write]'
            ]
        ]);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

           return response($response->getBody()->getContents(), $response->getStatusCode());
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return response($response->getBody()->getContents(), $response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

---

In order to investigate if this is actually an issue, I tried hitting the endpoint via Postman. It gets into the function, but it does not find the `auth()->user()`. I tried some other endpoints using the same route group, and it was able to find the `auth()->user()` with them. What might cause it to go missing like that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but maybe someone will find it helpful. In order to test the logout function you have provided you'll need to pass the token as authorization header.

```php
$response = $this->post('/logout', [], ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token])
                ->assertStatus(200);
```

I'm not sure why, but the access token can't be retrieved with `$user->token()` when using actingAs, but it can be retrieved with `$user->tokens()->first()`
.